# creating an array of returned results to display in messagebox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this method that returns to the user a messagebox displaying the results. But for multiple results there is message window that appears for each result. How can i create it so that the results are put into an array and then at the end display all the results to the user in one messagebox?

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in Comparer)
            {
                if (kvp.Value != 0)
                {
                    mismatches++;
                    string InWhich = kvp.Value > 0 ? firstFile : secondFile;
                    MessageBox.Show("Extra value \n"+kvp.Key+" \nfound in file " + InWhich);
                    if (Math.Abs(kvp.Value) != 1)
                        MessageBox.Show( Math.Abs(kvp.Value)+ "times");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` to build up the string in the loop, like this:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder theStringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in Comparer)
{
    if (kvp.Value != 0)
    {
        mismatches++;
        string InWhich = kvp.Value > 0 ? firstFile : secondFile;
        theStringBuilder.AppendLine("Extra value \n"+kvp.Key+" \nfound in file " + InWhich);
        if (Math.Abs(kvp.Value) != 1)
            theStringBuilder.AppendLine( Math.Abs(kvp.Value)+ "times");
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can display all of the contents in the `StringBuilder`, like this:

```
// Display all results in message box
MessageBox.Show(theStringBuilder.ToString());
```

UPDATE:

To store the changes of each file, use a `List<string>`, like this:

```
var firstFileChanges = new List<string>();
var secondFileChanges = new List<string>();

System.Text.StringBuilder theStringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in Comparer)
{
    if (kvp.Value != 0)
    {
        mismatches++;
        string InWhich = kvp.Value > 0 ? firstFile : secondFile;

        if(InWhich == firstFile)
        {
            firstFileChanges.Add(kvp.Key);
        }
        else 
        {
            secondFileChanges.Add(kvp.Key);
        }
    }
}

if(firstFileChanges.Count > 0 )
{
    theStringBuilder.Append("First file changes: ");

    int counter1 = 0;
    foreach(string change1 in firstFileChanges)
    {
        if(counter1 > 0)
        {
            theStringBuilder.Append(", ");
        }

        theStringBuilder.Append(change1);

        counter1 += 1;
    }

    theStringBuilder.AppendLine();
}

if(secondFileChanges.Count > 0 )
{
    theStringBuilder.Append("Second file changes: ");

    int counter2 = 0;
    foreach(string change2 in secondFileChanges)
    {
        if(counter2 > 0)
        {
            theStringBuilder.Append(", ");
        }

        theStringBuilder.Append(change2);

        counter2 += 1;
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(theStringBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: if i wanted to add a changes to a certain file could i also create a stringbuilder for it? so that i am not getting "file A added 2, file A added dog..." and have it file A added: 2, dog. ?

Comment: @Masriyah - sure, you can have more than one `StringBuilder`, but I am not sure what you mean by "changes to a certain file"?

Comment: here i have two files so the changes are either made to the first file or the second file. So if the changes where made to first file it will state `first file` once and list all the changes made in that file. rather than naming the file then the change and the same file name will show many times

Comment: See `UPDATE:` in answer for one way of doing what you asked about.

Comment: you are a STAR! Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2):

you can use `StringBuilder` as below

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in Comparer)
{
    if (kvp.Value != 0)
    {
        mismatches++;
        string InWhich = kvp.Value > 0 ? firstFile : secondFile;
        sb.AppendLine("Extra value \n" + kvp.Key + " \nfound in file " + InWhich + (Math.Abs(kvp.Value) != 1 ? ("\n" + Math.Abs(kvp.Value) + "times") : string.Empty)); 
    }
}
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

Or You can use LINQ

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n" ,Comparer.GroupBy(x => x.Value > 0)
                    .Select(g => string.Join("\n" , 
                            g.Select(l=> "Extra value \n" + l.Key + (Math.Abs(l.Value) != 1 ? ("\n" + Math.Abs(l.Value) + "times") : string.Empty))) +
                                " \nfound in file " + (g.Key ? firstFile : secondFile))));
```

Comment: i get an error stating that i cannot convert from string to bool

Comment: I like the linq i will give that a try

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in Comparer)
        {
            if (kvp.Value != 0)
            {
                mismatches++;
                string InWhich = kvp.Value > 0 ? firstFile : secondFile;
                //load the data in to a string - use string append
            }
        }

//outside the foreach loop
MessageBox.Show(....);
```